# Defining math shortcuts/macros for Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, latex, equations

Is it possible, in any version of Microsoft Word, to define shortcuts for recurring mathematical expressions? (preferably in a way that allows updating all occurences at once if needed)

For instance, in quantum mechanics a recurring structure is the state notation `|ψ⟩`* and `⟨ψ|`*. Depending on the context, more complex structures may appear repeatedly, e.g. `χ⁽²⁾`*. In LaTeX I'd use `\newcommand` to define my shortcut, often parametrized.

Despite many changes since older versions of Word, that would in theory make it a viable alternative for scientific writing (or at least viable when only MS Word documents are accepted by some entity) the ability to define such "macros" is essential to me. Does MS Word by now support something like this?

For *creating* repeating structures, I would use AutoHotKey. A Word-internal solution might however provide a lot more power and convenience.

***edit*** I meant especially parametrized structures, i.e. the equivalent of `\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}`.

---

*I used unicode symbols here that might not be supported on all systems. The equivalent latex code would be, in this order: `|\psi\rangle`, `\langle\psi|` and `\chi^{(2)}`.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is using AutoCorrect as described at the bottom of this page: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/autocorrect-spelling-and-insert-text-and-symbols-HA010354277.aspx

Essentially you would define a text equivalent for which Word would automatically substitute a symbol or set of symbols. For example:

To add an autocorrect entry in most recent versions of Word:

- Click the "Office" button at the top left, then the Word Options button
  [image: Word Options dialog]
- Click on Proofing in the left-hand list, then the button for AutoCorrect Options.
  [image: Word Options - Autocorrect]
- Click on the "Math Autocorrect" tab and check to see if the entry already exists.
- If not already in the list, enter the text you want to use in the left-hand box, e.g. where I have entered "|Y)" in the screenshot.  Enter the symbols in the right-hand box and click the "Add" button.

[image: Math AutoCorrect]

- OK your way back to the document.

Now each time you type the left-hand text, it will get replaced with the right-hand entry.

Comment: Is it possible with this to define *parametrized* structures? (see clarification-edit of my question). In most cases one parameter would suffice, i.e. e.g. inserting `|⟩` and then putting the cursor in the center. Also I notice this has no visible support for updating the replacement across a document (which, while optional, would be still helpful). Or can this, if needed, be done with search-and-replace, even if the structure is complex (e.g. a fraction).

Comment: Assuming that I understand what you mean by "parameterized", I think it's certainly possible to define.  As for updating throughout a document, you'd have to tell it to do so with Find & Replace, as you note, since the typed characters are more of a "shortcut" that, once expanded, is only seen as the inserted characters.  I think what you are up against is, simply enough, that text processors are not the best tools for entry of mathematics symbols, but I don't know of any standard word processing program that can do more than this. Formula construction via toolbar is slow by comparison.

Answer (score 0):

**It is now (2022) *sort of* possible.**  "Parameterization" is accomplished with a dialog box.

Here is a simple example of a "Create Bra|Ket" dialog with four controls: a textbox to enter the custom LaTeX string; "Bra" and "Ket" command buttons to transform that into something else in LaTeX and append them to the selection; and a "Make Equation" command button to convert the selection into an Equation Editor object.

The first figure shows the dialog and the document after pressing the "Bra" button.

[image: Figure 1]

In order to permit additional processing, I don't automatically convert the selection into an equation.  For instance, if a "ket" is next inserted, the underlying code merges the two vertical bars (at the end of the "bra" and beginning of the "ket"):

[image: Figure 2]

Now the "Make Equation" command button will convert this into an Equation Editor object:

[image: Figure 3]

---

The following code isn't bulletproof--it just demonstrates proof of concept.

**The first subroutine is the key:** these two lines convert the selection into an Equation Editor object and then parse the LaTeX strings.  This subroutine is called when the "Make Equation" button (*aka* `CommandButton1`) is clicked:

```vba
Private Sub Text2Equation()
    Selection.OMaths.Add Range:=Selection.Range
    Selection.OMaths.BuildUp
End Sub
```

**The rest is just dialog code.**  This is where the TeX macro is implemented by means of string concatenation.  The `Click()` event code demonstrates that you can compute with the text, modifying it as needed, to create whatever custom LaTeX string you want out of the material entered into the dialog box.

```vba
Private Sub CommandButton_Ket_Click()
    Dim s As String
    s = Trim(Selection.Text)
    If Len(s) > 0 Then
        If Mid(s, Len(s), 1) = "|" Then
            Selection.InsertAfter Text:=Bra_Ket.TextBox1.Text & "\rangle_^*"
            Else
            Selection.InsertAfter Text:="|" & Bra_Ket.TextBox1.Text & "\rangle_^*"
            End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton_Bra_Click()
    Selection.InsertAfter Text:="\langle " & Bra_Ket.TextBox1.Text & "|"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Text2Equation
End Sub
```

---

This approach is a little involved--much more so than writing a LaTeX command macro--but it is readily extendable once you get this much working.  Create separate small dialogs for favorite macros or to search and replace material (warning: I have no idea how to search for Equation Editor objects and suspect it might not be possible).  Or, create one monster dialog to select from a list of options.